# Is there any advantage to using $\chi^2$ for checking linear relationship $y(x)$?

Tags: chi-squared-test, linear

At my university (physics major), we are often forced to use $\chi^2$ for checking if $y(x)$, where $y$ and $x$ are measured, is linear. We fit a linear regression $f(x)$ and then use

$\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \Big( \frac{y_i-f(x_i)}{\sigma_i} \Big)^2$

Where $\sigma_i$ is an error of measurement of $y$, for example, time measurement: $y = (10 \pm \sigma)$ seconds, it comes from the fact that our stopwatch isn't perfect.

There are other methods for checking linearity, like $R^2$, Pearson correlation coefficient, lack-of-fit, or whatever else.

Is $\chi^2$ good for that?

Comment: Can you explain what sigma is?  What is the "uncertainty (error) of y"? Obviously it can't be y minus the predicted value, since that's the numerator....

Comment: Sigma is error of measurement of y, for example time measurement: y = (10 ± sigma) seconds, it comes from the fact that our stopwatch isn't perfect

Comment: It's above my level of expertise, but I don't see how this tests for linearity....  In any case, it's not a bad idea to ask professors of they have a reference for this that explains the derivations and uses of this formula.

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436201/p-value-fitting-a-model-to-data