# p-value fitting a model to data

Tags: p-value, least-squares, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, chi-squared-distribution

I have performed a physical experiment with few (~20) measurements, which have different uncertainties on the y-axis. The measurements were fitted to an exponential model $f(x)=ae^{-bx}+c$ using [scipy.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) with uncertainties as sigma, so the fit that was chosen minimizes the sum of the squares of the residuals divided by the uncertainty.

These are my results and the fit I got:
[image]
I calculated the Chi-Squared value for my fit as follows: $\chi^2_{min}=\sum_{i=1}^N(\frac{y_i-f(x_i)}{\sigma_i})^2=30.3$
(f is my model with fitted parameters and $\sigma_i$ is my uncertainty on the i-th measurement) and normalizing by the degrees of freedom I got a Chi-Squared reduced value of $\chi^2_{red}=\frac{\chi^2_{min}}{N-k}=2.0$ where N is the number of measurements and k is the number of parameters I have fitted (3 for my model with parameters a, b and c).
This value makes sense to me, as visually the fit looks reasonable ($\chi^2_{red}\approx1$ is expected for a good fit).

Now, I also wanted to calculate the **p-value** of my fit, that is to test the null-hypothesis that the parameters I have calculated are correct, and see what was the probability of getting a result more extreme (i.e. higher $\chi^2_{min}$ value).

As far as I understood, my $\chi^2_{min}$ should be drawn from a $\chi^2$ distribution with k degrees of freedom (I assume that my errors are random), so my p-value should be calculated as $1 - \chi^2_{CDF}(\chi^2_{min}=30.3, N-k)$, i.e. chances of getting a *higher* $\chi^2_{min}$ for this amount of DOF.
However, calculating with [scipy.stats.chi2.cdf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2.html) this gives me a p-value of 0.01, which if I understand correctly means that my measurements are at the 0.01 "extreme" of the model (99% of experiments should give smaller $\chi^2_{min}$).

This result is confusing for me, because the fit looks (visually) reasonable, and the $\chi^2_{red}$ value is quite close to 1, indicating a good fit.

My questions follow:

- Are my methods for calculating the goodness-of-fit correct?
- How come such a low p-value accompanies this $\chi^2_{red}$ value?

Comment: There may be a confusion between the number of points and the number of cells in your calculation of $\chi^2$: the number of cells is about 20, but the number of points is much bigger, since you could  calculate the standard deviations. Also your curve visibly does not pass through the error bars. Your $\chi^2$ indicates that on average you err by $2\sigma$ - only 5% of the data should fall in this range.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what are cells and points? I'm unfamiliar with these in this context.

Comment: You fit doesn't look that great: relative to the error bars shown, the fit is too high near $x=8,x=9$ and too low near $25 \le x \le 50.$  The p-value of 0.01 looks correctly computed, assuming the $\chi^2$ statistic really is 30.3. One reason potentially to doubt the latter is that the $\sigma_i$ are likely estimates themselves and thereby might introduce more uncertainty into the statistic.  It would help to know their origin.  The serial correlation in the residuals raises another set of concerns about the calculation of this p-value. We need to understand the experiment.